# Why isn't Spring Data Rest compatible with Spring's Feign on query parameter list?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-cloud-feign

Using @FeignClient to pass a collection via:

```
@GetMapping("/api/cars/search/findCarsByIdIn")  
CollectionModel<Cars> getCars(
                @RequestParam("carIds") 
                Collection<Integer> carIds);
```

Causes the URL to look like this:

`http://car-service/api/cars/search/findCarsByIdIn?carIds=33&carIds=46`

But Spring Data Rest is expecting this:

`http://car-service/api/cars/search/findCarsByIdIn?carIds=33,46`

Spring Data REST throws an error:

> class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer
> (java.lang.String and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of
> loader 'bootstrap')

How can I change the feign client or Spring Data Rest to be compatible with each other?